How can I run multiple physical iOS devices with Appium?
I am trying to run a multiple physical iOS devices on Appium but it keeps crashing / not connecting
I set up 2 different servers at first and tried running with different ports - that led to crashes and scripts stopped mid way.
I understand it has to do with the WebDriver needing to run on a different port, as it's already taken, the other server is trying to make a request and the socket refuses connection and it crashes.
I tried running
appium server --driver-xcuitest-webdriveragent-port 810x

but now it won't connection was refused to port 810x, socket hang up. can someone help me please?

You can take a look at "Appium Device Farm". Its one of the most popular project for creating and managing a device farm of iOS and Android devices.
Documentation for the same can be found here : https://devicefarm.org/
